# PyWin32 - Object of type 'NonType' has no len()

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a .exe out of my python script on my Windows 8.1 laptop. At first I tried py2exe and the .exe loads but won't open. I then tried installing pyinstaller, but got the error that I need PyWin32. I downloaded pywin32-219 and tried to install it, but I get the error 'Object of type 'NonType' has no len()'. I tried to pip install the file cp27 file from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) but I get the error that 'pywin32‑219‑cp26‑none‑win32.whl' is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error from your `.py` file with your interpreter?

Comment: The python script that I want to convert to .exe works fine in the Python shell.

Comment: Make sure to install the pywin32 file appropriate to your Python version. It sounds like you tried to install `cp26` into Python2.7 - you'll need `cp27` for that.